# Escape quotes when building javascript from php

Tags: php, javascript, escaping

Basically, I'm taking user input and passing it to a javascript function in a page from php. But because the user use's apostrophes, I'm getting errors. What's  the proper escape function in php to use on a variable that will be surrounded by quotes. IE:

Some php:

```
$userString = "Joe's Pizza";
// escape here
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">myFunction('$userString');</script>";
```

Thanks much!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[addslashes](http://php.net/manual/en/function.addslashes.php); e.g.

```
$userString = addslashes("Joe's Pizza");
print '<script type="text/javascript">myFunction('$userString');</script>";;
```

Comment: Please, please don't do this.

Comment: Well, he asked. What would you suggest anyways?

Comment: @Alien, there's no real problem with addslashes here (as opposed to database escaping where there's a huge problem).  It's just not as flexible.

Comment: Seems to be good enough, especially since this is just coming out of a database and I'm using mysql_real_escape_string on its way in. I don't see any problems with using this right now. Thanks.

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 6):

Wrap it in an object/associative array and use `json_encode`.

```
$array = array('data' => $userString);
$encoded_array = json_encode($array);
echo "<script type=\"text/javascript\">myFunction($encoded_array);</script>";
```

myFunction could look like:

```
function myFunction(obj)
{
  var data = obj.data;
  ... 
}
```

This also allows you to easily make the object more complex if needed.

Comment: I don't need an array in this particular instance, so I'm going to go with the other alternative, but a good suggestion. I generally have just constructed my json objects as strings, but this is clearly a better way to do it. So, I will be using this when I need a more complex object to be returned.